# Построить дерево Nested Set

Tags: php, nested-sets

Из плоского массива:

```
$tmp = array(
    array('id' => 0, 'level' => 0, 'name' => 'root', 'left' => 1, 'right' => 13),
    array('id' => 1, 'level' => 1, 'name' => 'Техотдел', 'left' => 2, 'right' => 8),
    array('id' => 2, 'level' => 1, 'name' => 'Отдел кадров', 'left' => 9, 'right' => 10),
    array('id' => 3, 'level' => 1, 'name' => 'Экономический отдел', 'left' => 11, 'right' => 12),
    array('id' => 4, 'level' => 2, 'name' => 'Подотдел техотдела 1', 'left' => 3, 'right' => 6),
    array('id' => 5, 'level' => 2, 'name' => 'Подотдел техотдела 2', 'left' => 7, 'right' => 8),
    array('id' => 6, 'level' => 3, 'name' => 'Подподотдел техотдела 1', 'left' => 4, 'right' => 5),
);
```

Необходимо построить дерево вида:

```
$tree = array(
array(
    'id' => 0,
    'level' => 0,
    'name' => 'root',
    'children' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'Техотдел',
            'children' => array(
                array(
                    'id' => 4,
                    'level' => 2,
                    'name' => 'Подотдел техотдела 1',
                    'children' => array(
                        array(
                            'id' => 6,
                            'level' => 3,
                            'name' => 'Подподотдел техотдела 1'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'id' => 5,
                    'level' => 2,
                    'name' => 'Подотдел техотдела 2'
                ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'Отдел кадров'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 3,
            'level' => 1,
            'name' => 'Экономический отдел'
        ),
    )
),
);
```

Голову ломаю, не могу сообразить как это сделать.

Comment: поясните что у вас тут значит `left` и `right` ?

Comment: да и вообще принцип построения такого дерева на имеющихся данных. я что то связи не вижу. Пример ведь исходных данных и  результирующего дерева соответствуют друг другу? где информация о родительском узле хранится, или о потомках? Пока что ясна только иерархия по `level`

Comment: @teran эти ключи организуют хранение иерархичных структур данных  в реляционной базе данных - http://www.getinfo.ru/article610.html

Comment: а, самое главное я заголовке я упустил (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, алгоритм решения не один существует, так что простой вариант построения:

Сначала определим максимальную глубину и разложим массив на уровни:

```
$lmax = max(array_column($tmp, 'level'));

$levels = array_fill(0, $lmax, []);
foreach($tmp as $node){
    $levels[$node['level']][] = $node + ['children' => []];
}
```

Теперь собственно определим функцию построения. На вход нужен родительских узел. Будем перебирать элементы, которые лежат на уровень ниже. Если нижний элемент подходит под граничные условия, то добавляем его к `children`. Далее запускаем рекурсию.

```
$build = function(&$root) use (&$build, $levels){
            $l = $root['level'] + 1;
            if(!isset($levels[$l])) return;

            foreach($levels[$l] as &$n){
                if(($n['id'] >= $root['left']) && ($n['id'] <= $root['right'])){
                    $root['children'][] = &$n;
                    $build($n);
                }
            }
        };
```

Следует обратить внимание на использование ссылок `&` как в цикле перебора, так и при добавлении в `children`

Осталось запустить это дело.

```
$root = $levels[0][0];
$build($root);
print_r($root);
```

На выходе искомая структура.

В принципе можно попутно удалять элементы из `$levels`, которые вносим в `children`, чтобы в следующие разы (в рекурсиях) их уже не перебирать.

Comment: Я шмагла)), поправил чутка код, т.к. имею дело с php 5.3.13(:, наворотил globals и все заработало. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Врядли этот код будет работать в иных случаях, кроме эталонного из темы поста.

По коду идет сравнение ID узлов и границ LEFT и RIGHT дерева.

Только вот в Nested Sets ID  к границам не имеет никакого отношения.

Дерево может состоять из 4-х элементов с ID 1000, 1001, 2376, 7866
но LEFT и RIGHT  у него будут от 1 до 8.